# I can't add datapusher-plus to my CKAN in docker

Tags: docker, datastore, ckan, opendata

I tried to make a Dockerized CKAN (opendata portal) with datapusher-plus but I can't do it, do you have a solution because I want to recover the data from the xlsx files which does not work with datapusher

my repo ro help me : https://github.com/FWICSS/dockerized-ckan

Comment: in order to get a good answer to your question, you need to ask the question in the recommended way. You can find how to ask a question here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: ok thanks I will fix it